# Change of basis regarding normal / tangential coordinates to polar coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm working with kinematics at the moment. I've realized that it's pretty simple to translate between polar and cartesian coordinates. The same goes for normal and tangential coordinates to cartesian coordinates. However, I wonder whether there's a simple (maybe general too for that case) way of going directly from normal / tangential coordinates to polar coordinates or vice versa without going "through" the cartesian coordinates.

This question arised since I was looking through some solution to a problem I struggled to solve, and where I found that the teacher had added the radial component and the angular component in the r - $\theta$ - system to get the tangential component in the n - t - system. Maybe this was only a special case?

Thanks!

Comment: I think from normal-tangential to Cartesian is problem dependent. On the same basis normal-tangential to polar (cylindrical) should be problem dependent as well considering the fact that Cartesian and cylindrical may be uniquely mapped to each other.

Comment: @Newbie Thank you for your answer. I get it :)